# Rendering more than one chart with Highcharts using Angular js Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

i'm having an issue while trying to render more than one chart with Highcharts and AngularJS.

My code is based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csTzc/

I basically just duplicated the div where the chart is rendered: http://jsfiddle.net/CloudStrife91/b4vpP/

```
<div class="hc-pie" items="ideas"></div>
<div class="hc-pie" items="ideas2"></div>
```

As you can see the second chart is not displayed instead there is the template div that says "not working"

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: The first thing that I immediately notice is that you are re-using the `id="container"`.  There is only supposed to be one element on a page with the same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change how you provide the element in the `renderTo` of HighCharts.

Change

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: "container",
      ...
    },
    ... 
  });
```

To

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: element[0],
      ...
    },
    ... 
  });
```

You should also remove the `id="container"` part from the template, you don't need it there and like I mentioned in my comment, it is invalid html to have more than element with the same id.

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4vpP/4/)